# Como fazer com CSS um fundo quadriculado tipo tabuleiro de Xadrez para o Body?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Gostaria de colocar no `<body>` um fundo quadriculado, tipo um tabuleiro de Xadrez cobrindo todo o body.

Tentei com `repeating-linear-gradient()`, mas não consegui...

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0, black 20px, transparent 20px, transparent 40px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0, #fff 20px, black 20px, black 40px);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **OBS:** Usar 1 milhão de `div`s ou `table` não vai servir, preciso aplicar no fundo do `body`

Comment: uma imagem levinha com `repeat` não ficaria bom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depois de testar a solução dos colegas vi que existia um problema, que acredito ser renderização, no FireFox, Edge e IE. Como visto na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha solução foi usar um **SVG inline**, no lugar do `background-image`: Dessa forma com apenas poucas linhas é possível fazer um fundo quadriculado até mais fácil de customizar que o feito com `linear-gradiente`, não é feita requisição no server, pois o `SVG` está inline e também foi possível fazer um *fallback* com outro `backgraund` caso o browser do usuário não de suporte ao SVG. `(recomendo que testem no IE caso tenham interesse para ver que ele usa o segundo URL como` background `e ignora o primeiro)`

**Segue o resultado básico.** *Lembrado que vc pode facilmente alterar o tamanho dos blocos pelo `background-size` E a cor de cada quadrado individualmente pelo `fill` do `rect`, Inclusive dentro de cada quadrado vc pode ter um gradiente diferente...*

```css
body {
    background-image:
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,\
            <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>\
                <rect fill='%23000' width='50' height='50' x='0' y='0' />\
                <rect fill='%23000' width='50' height='50' x='50' y='50' />\
                <rect fill='%23fff' width='50' height='50' x='50' y='0' />\
                <rect fill='%23fff' width='50' height='50' x='0' y='50' />\
            </svg>"),
        url(https://abrilveja.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/mallandro.png);
    background-size: 80px, cover;
}
```

***Abaixo um resultado mostrado a versatilidade das cores no bg  caso queira algo diferente.***

```css
body {
    background-image:
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,\
            <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>\
                <defs>\
                    <linearGradient id='grad1' x1='0%' y1='0%' x2='100%' y2='0%'>\
                        <stop offset='0%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1' />\
                        <stop offset='100%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1' />\
                    </linearGradient>\
                </defs>\
                <rect fill='url(#grad1)' width='50' height='50' x='0' y='0' />\
                <rect fill='black' width='50' height='50' x='50' y='50' />\
                <rect fill='blue' width='50' height='50' x='50' y='0' />\
                <rect fill='%23fff' width='50' height='50' x='0' y='50' />\
            </svg>"),
        url(https://abrilveja.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/mallandro.png);
    background-size: 30px, cover;
}
```

---

## EDITE:

**Nova técnica**

Nova solução usando `mix-blend-mode`, porém não funciona no IE ou EDGE, vc pode consultar o suporte do seu browser aqui https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mix-blend-mode

A técnica é colocar dois pseudo elementos no body um `::before` e um `::after` e faz neles o `mix-blend-mode` junto com um `repeating-linear-gradient`. O blend mode `difference` faz com que as cores sobrepostas se invertam, então onde tem uma linha preta passando sobre a outra linha preta na intercessão entre elas vai ficar um "quadrado branco", gerando esse efeito de tabuleiro de xadrez

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

body::before, body::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #000 0, #000 40px, #fff 40px, #fff 80px);
}
body::after {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0, #000 40px, #fff 40px, #fff 80px);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Comment: interessante, gerou os quadros alternados no svg bem legal :)
mais claro de entender que o background com gradient

Comment: @RicardoPontual pois é, ficou bem versátil e fácil de entender. Além de resolver o problema da "linha fantasma". []'s

Comment: Muito legal, mas esse segundo deu uma dor de cabeça, não precisava

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam foi só para testar as possibilidades rss, tentei até colocar um dos quadrados como uma imagem "embebedada" dentro do rect, mas acho que pelo estilo inline como usei não aceita. De qq forma ta ai uma solução alternativa

Answer (score 2):

Pegando a sua ideia e adaptando com umas dicas da internet, cheguei nesse resultado:

```css
body {
    background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    -moz-background-size:100px 100px;
    background-size:100px 100px;
    -webkit-background-size:101px 101px;
    background-position:0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```

No lugar de quadrados, triângulos ( `45deg` no `linear-gradient`)

Comment: No Chrome até ficou ok, mas no FireFox e no Edge ficou com uma "linha" branca atravessando os quadrados na diagonal... Parece algum tipo de problema de renderização ou algo do tipo. testa ai

Comment: a linha que faz o ajuste disso é `-webkit-background-size:101px 101px;`, incluir `background-size: 101px 101px` ou outro valor deve resolver

Comment: Cara tentei vários valores ali e nada resolve, basta vc mesmo abrir com esse código no FireFox que vc vai entender o que estou falando... Já tentei em duas maquinas diferentes e o problema permanece. IE, EDGE e FF todos apresentam o problema...

Comment: Consegui uma solução que renderiza direito, é inline apesar de ser svg, tem fallback para IE, e é talvez mais fácil e versátil que linear-gradiente, mas valeu a força.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background:
      -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
      -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    background:
      -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
      -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    background:
      linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
      linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    -moz-background-size:100px 100px;
    background-size:100px 100px;
    -webkit-background-size:101px 101px;
    background-position:0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```

Só errou os valores [fonte](http://www.guj.com.br/t/background-xadrez-com-css-resolvido/193539/19)

Comment: No Chrome até ficou ok, mas no FireFox e no Edge ficou com uma "linha" branca atravessando os quadrados na diagonal... Parece algum tipo de problema de renderização ou algo do tipo. testa ai

Comment: Jovem obrigado pela ajuda, mas resolvi usando un SVG inline como background e funcionou perfeitamente, é ainda mais fácil de customizar que com linear-gradiente e não da problema de renderização. Valeu a ajuda.