# Tabuleiro de xadrez css

Tags: css

Estou com dificuldade em montar um tabuleiro de xadrez, deixei 4x4 só por questão de estética mesmo, alguém poderia me ajudar com a resolução disto?

```js
 casas = 4

 for(i=0;i<casas;i++){
  for(j=0;j<casas;j++){
   tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div></div>"
  }
 }
```

```css
 #tabuleiro{
  width: 400px;
 }
 #tabuleiro div{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;  
 }
 #tabuleiro div:nth-child(2n){
  background-color: #b58763
 }

 #tabuleiro div:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: #f0dab5
 }
```

```html
<div id='tabuleiro'></div>
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida exatamente? Em que ponto está tendo dificuldade?

Comment: Respostas só com CSS: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319900/como-fazer-com-css-um-fundo-quadriculado-tipo-tabuleiro-de-xadrez-para-o-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
casas = 4

for(i=0;i<casas;i++){
  for(j=0;j<casas;j++){
    if(i%2 ==0){
      if(j%2 == 0){
        tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div class='black'></div>"
      }else{
        tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div></div>"
      }
    }else{
      if(j%2 == 0){
        tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div></div>"
      }else{
        tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div class='black'></div>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#tabuleiro{
  width: 400px;
}
#tabuleiro div{
  background-color: #f0dab5;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;  
}
#tabuleiro div.black{
  background-color: #b58763
}
```

```html
<div id='tabuleiro'></div>
```

Fiz uma solução bem mais simples, utilizei a matriz que você criou usando os dois **for** i e j, dar uma olhadinha!

https://codepen.io/caioalexandrebr/pen/vvPZor

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma validação e marcação de classe para linhas impares e pares:

```js
casas = 4

for (i = 0; i < casas; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < casas; j++) {
    if(i%2==0){
      tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div class='linha-par'></div>"
    }else{
      tabuleiro.innerHTML += "<div class='linha-impar'></div>"
    }
    
  }
}
```

```css
#tabuleiro {
  width: 400px;
}

#tabuleiro div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#tabuleiro div.linha-par:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #b58763
}

#tabuleiro div.linha-par:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #f0dab5
}

#tabuleiro div.linha-impar:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f0dab5
}

#tabuleiro div.linha-impar:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #b58763
}
```

```html
<div id='tabuleiro'></div>
```